# SQL Server 2012 developer and express version

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm not sure whether sql server 2012 developer edition can be installed to a Windows Server 2008/2012 for testing and development purpose. On the other hand, it seems express version has a limitation of 10GB database size, does it mean all databases 10GB, or it can create multiple databases, and each database 10GB?
Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Question**

Yes, you can. Have a look at this link http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Install-SQL-Server-2012-P1.html

**Second Question**

It is 10 GB per Database. You can have 10 databases of 10GB size each. Which means 100GBs of Databases.

Comment: If we install a developer edition to a testing Windows server. How many licenses should buy if two developers will use it to do development and two users will connect to the database via a web application to do the testing

Comment: @user3691709 Here you go buddy. https://www.directionsonmicrosoft.com/licensing/2013/06/licensing-sql-server-development-and-test

Comment: Thanks, how about UAT user for testing the web application to developer database, need licenses also?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the developer edition, but I suppose yes, it doesn't matters if it's installed on a server or on a developer machine, as long as it's used just for testing and development only and not for real production usage.

About the express edition, the limitation is 10GB *per database*. You can have as many as you want, whose totaling size can be as big as you want, as long as each one, individually, is smaller than 10GB.